# Ways to save changes in dataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, ado.net

I have a database with 8 tables, i fill my datagridview and then save changes using the same block of code for each table, but i can only save 4 of 8 tables, the other 4 tables gives me an error
`Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records` whe i try to save the changes in them

This is how i fill my dataGridView:

```
{
string script = "SELECT * FROM hatr.rbt;";
mycon = new MySqlConnection(connect);
mycon.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter ms_data = new MySqlDataAdapter(script, connect);
SD.DataTable table = new SD.DataTable();
ms_data.Fill(table);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
mycon.Close();
ds.AcceptChanges();
}
```

And this is how i save the changes:

```
{
string script = "SELECT id, name, Model_preparation_R_Hr, Time_for_preparation_hr, Time_for_post_processing_hr, YZV_work FROM rbt;";
mycon = new MySqlConnection(connect);
mycon.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter ms_data = new MySqlDataAdapter(script, connect);
var cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(ms_data);
cb.GetInsertCommand();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ms_data.Update(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable);
ms_data.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
ms_data.InsertCommand.CommandText += "; select * from rbt where id = last_insert_id();";
ms_data.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord;        
}
```

I also know that the error occurs in the line:

```
ms_data.Update(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable);
```

Both blocks of code are the same for every table, but the second block which is need to save changes in dataGrid for some reason gives me an updateCommand error i mentioned before, i couldn't figure out why i get this error for some tables and why i dont get it for others.
So maybe there is some other way to save changes in dataGridView? Because this is the only one i could come up with for now

Comment: If some tables work, and other tables don't work, seems like maybe something about the tables themselves. Do all of the tables have a primary key, and AUTO_INCREMENT defined?

Comment: @Loathing all the tables have PK's and none of them have auto_increment defined, even those that work, i can also say that for example in the table that i work with in the block of code i mentioned in the question before, i have 4 rows there and i cant update first and second row, i get an error, but 3 and 4 rows i can update without any issue for some reason

Comment: And also i made this database in mysql workbench and everything work there, i can update all the tables and i dont get any errors. But maybe when i try to work with some of the tables through my Application, can there be a reason in triggers? Maybe some of the triggers do not work properly when i update database through my App, can this be the reason of the error message?

Comment: Then why are you calling `last_insert_id()`? The documentation says, "The `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function returns the `AUTO_INCREMENT` id of the last row that has been inserted or updated in a table."

Comment: when i get the error i dont even get to the line with last_insert_id, i get the error before this line so this is not the case in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have found a reason of the `Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records` error. Considering that i have created my database in **MySql Workbench** and i was trying to work with it through **dataGridView** in my App i have found out that there is a conflict between FLOAT fields in **MySql Workbench** and **dataGridView**. When you create a float number in MySql Workbench it should be written with a dot like **"0.1"** and it appears that in dataGridView it should be written with comma like **"0,1"** so the one float field but in to different situations: in mysql Workbench and dataGridView has two different ways to be written and it occurs an Error, as i see this situation, i can be wrong in some ways of course, but i just recreated all FLOAT fields as DOUBLE and now it works.